# Use regex to replace words before any digit with nothing

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace words and spaces that appear before a digit in a string with nothing. For example, for the string = 'Juice of 1/2', I want to return '1/2'. I tried the following, but it did not work.

```
string = "Juice of 1/2"
new = string.replace(r"^.+?(?=\d)", "")
```

Also I am trying to perform this on every cell of a list of columns using the following code. How would I incorporate the new regex pattern into the existing pattern of r"(|)|?

```
df[pd.Index(cols2) + "_clean"] = (
    df[cols2]
    .apply(lambda col: col.str.replace(r"\(|\)|,", "", regex=True))

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.+?` will match anything, including other digits. It will also match the `/` in `1/2`. Since you only want to replace letters and spaces, use `[a-z\s]+`.

You also have to use `re.sub()`, not `string.replace()` (in Pandas, `.str.replace()` processes regular expressions by default).

```
new = re.sub(r'[a-z\s]+(?=\d)', '', string, flags=re.I)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to phrase this using `str.extract`:

```py
df["col2"] = df["col2"].str.extract(r'([0-9/-]+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this might work.

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[A-Za-z\s]+"

test_str = "Juice of 1/2 hede"

subst = ""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```